# Question on Singular homology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

i have this example :

The homology of the space $X=\lbrace x \rbrace$ .

for all $p\geq 0$, there is a unique singular p-simplex $\sigma_p:\Delta_p\rightarrow X$,
and for $p>0$ we have $\partial_i\sigma_p=\sigma_{p-1}$ so

$\partial\sigma_p=(\sum_{i=0}^p (-1)^i)\sigma_{p-1}= 0 ~~\text{if $p$ is odd and }~~\sigma_{p-1} ~~\text{if not}$

so the singular chains complexe is $\mathbb{A} \stackrel{0}\longleftarrow \mathbb{A}\stackrel{id}\longleftarrow \mathbb{A}...$

I dont understand why $C_0(X,\mathbb{A})=C_1(X,\mathbb{A})=...=\mathbb{A}$

Please help me

Thank you.

Comment: What is $\Bbb A$?

Comment: I am slightly confused - for an $m$-dimensional simplicial complex shouldn't $C_n(X,\mathbb{A})=0$ if $n>m$?

Comment: it is the :unitary ring

Comment: @levitopher no i don't think that !

Comment: The chain group is generated by the unique simplex, so it is isomorphic to $\Bbb A$.

Comment: the unicity of the singular simplex is due to the fact that $X=\lbrace x \rbrace$ ?

Comment: Yes, there can be only one.

Comment: @StefanH thank you , so for all p there is one singular p-simplexe , or for each p there is one ?

Comment: The $n$-dimensional groups $C_n(X,\mathbb{A})$ are free abelian groups with basis the open $n$-simplices of $X$. These do not exist for $n>0$ since the space $X=\{x\}$ is zero-dimensional, so what am I missing?

Comment: @levitopher: Perhaps you are confusing simplicial and singular homology.

Comment: @Stefan: I wasn't confusing them I misread the question! Thanks for clarification.

Comment: @StefanH for p=0 there is a une sigular 0-simplexe, for p=i also there is unique singular i-simplexe but different , right ?

Comment: The singular $n$-simplex $σ^n$ is always the constant map $\triangle^n\to\{x\}$, even for $n=0$ where $△^n$ is just a point.

Comment: Please @StefanH how can we define the isomorphism between $C_p(X)$ and $\mathbb{A}$ ? please

Comment: It is $a\cdot\sigma_p\mapsto a$.

Comment: it is surjectif by definition , but for the injectivity ?$\phi(a_1.\sigma^1_p)=\phi(a_2.\sigma^2_p)=\Rightarrow a_1=a_2$ but how to obtain that $a_1.\sigma^1_p=a_2\sigma_p^2 $?? please

Comment: or @StefanH we dont change $\sigma_p$ ?

Comment: We don't change the $\sigma_p$. The module $C_p(X)$ consists of all $\Bbb A$-linear combinations of singular simplices in $X$. In this case, it consists of all elements of the form $a\cdot\sigma_p,\ a\in\Bbb A$.

Answer (score 0):

For $p\geqslant 0$ the group $C_p(X,A)$ is a free $A$-module generated by one element $\sigma_p$; it follows that $C_p(X,A)\cong A$ by mapping $\sigma_p$ to $1$ and extending linearly.